# Phpspreadsheet - set Hyperlink for cell

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am doing export CSV using phpspreadsheet. I want to set clickable URL for some cell.
What I have tried:

```
public function generateOfferLetterLogCsv($params)
{
    $title = $params['title'];
    $name = $params['name'];
    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
    $results = $params['results'];
    $formatType = $params['formatType'];
    $now = new \DateTime('now');
    $dateMonth = $now->format('d F Y');

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $spreadsheet->getProperties()->setCreator('Benerite HR');
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $row = 1;
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, 'Action');
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(9, $row, 'Content');

    $row++;

    foreach ($results as $data) {
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row, $data['action']);
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('I'.$row, 'www.phpexcel.net');
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('I'.$row)->getHyperlink()->setUrl('https://www.example.com');
        $row++;
    }

    $this->output($spreadsheet, $name, $formatType);
}
```

But this is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

CSV is a pure text dataformat. You must export a .xslx or an .xls file.